# foreach to get unique colors per column using apache velocity

Tags: apache, foreach, colors, velocity

So this is under a `"col-sm-4"`, which means up to three products can be seen. This is for the comparison of products, I wanted to create a way the customers can view the items in different colors and here is my code so far:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal">
    <img src="#magicUrl(" $product.media.get( 'primary').url ")" class="img-responsive primary-img">
</a>
<a data-trigger="PRODUCTListPageImg: $product.name" 
   data-track='{ "track": "Clicked the product img on product list page: $product.name" }' 
   href="#toroUrl(" $product.url ")">
    <b><h4 class="pro-name">Name: $product.name </h4></b>
</a>
<hr>
<h5>Price: $product.defaultSku.retailPrice</h5>

<h5>Other Colors:</h5> 
#if ( $preview ) 
    #set ( $product = $searcher.search('en_name_s:**', false).products.get(0)) 
#else 
    #set ( $product = $searcher.search('id:$product.id', false).products.get(0)) 
#end

<div class="row">
    #if($product.getAdditionalSkus()) 
        #foreach($productOption in $product.getAdditionalSkus()) 
            #foreach($productOptionVal in $productOption.getAllSkuOptionValueXrefs() )
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail thumb-cont">
                        <img class="thumb-img" src="#magicUrl(" $productOption.getSkuMedia().get( 'primary').url ")" 
                             alt="" 
                             data-value="$productOptionVal.getProductOptionValue().attributeValue">
                    </a>
                </div>
            #end 

            ##end foreach #end ##end foreach #else #foreach($media in $product.media) #if($media.key != "primary")
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <a class="thumbnail thumb-cont">
                    <img class="thumb-img" src="#magicUrl($media.url)" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
        #end 
      #end 

      #end ##-- This is superfluous at present
</div>
```

The primary image changes but the other 2 images in other columns change too... I am a beginner in apache velocity and am hoping that someone might be able to help me.

Comment: In your description you mentioned a class `col-sm-4` that is never used in your code. Also your code contains a syntax error. Would you please edit this. It will be better to get where to put the colors and to provide a solution that actually meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
#set($myColor = 0)
#foreach($element in $listOfElements)
    #set($myColor = $myColor + ${foreach.count} * 10)
    #if($myColor > 360)
        #set($myColor = $myColor - 360)
    #end

    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: hsl(${myColor}, 96%, 47%);">
        ...
    </div>
#end
```

How does it work?:
Basically it uses the loop counter `${foreach.count}` to increase the value of the color. You can change `10` in `${foreach.count} * 10` to any other value if the colors are varying to much or to little.

I use hsl colors here, because of the circle principle, where you either can easily start fresh when reaching 360°, like I did in the example or leave it to your browser, for 400° equals 40°.

Put a style attribute where it belongs. As you see it overrules the class attributes.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for causing trouble but I got it working by using js instead

```
 $('.thumb-img').on('click', function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).closest('.item-container').find('.primary-img').attr('src', url);
```

it was easier just finding its parent than going through loops in velocity
thank you for the effort tho